# Convert date string with abbreviation to datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, abbreviation

I have to convert multiple format of string with abbreviations into `datetime`.

```
17 - 21 Jan
Dienstag, 28. Dez.
31. Dez. - 4. Jan.
```

Here dates are in German but it can be in French, English, or Spanish.

Comment: What have you tried already? Will you know which dates are in which locale in advance? What range of potential date formats might there be?

Comment: set the appropriate [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html), then parse string to datetime with appropriate [parsing directive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should tell us the expected output format (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd, mm/yy....)

Besides that, you can use regex to find the pattern as this pic below:

[image: I'm using https://regex101.com/ site.]

Comment: An answer should provide an answer, not another question, no? That's what comments are for... Also, pictures of code are kind of not helpful in most cases; text = copy & paste